# Search exhaustively through a knowledge base in Prolog through a query

Tags: prolog

If I have a knowledge base of people and their birthdays like:

```
birthYear( adam , 2000 ).
birthYear( bob  , 2001 ).
birthYear( john , 2002 ).
```

How would I create a query to exhaustively search the knowledge base to find the youngest person without modifying the knowledge base?

Comment: Using findall/3 and minlist or maxlist

Answer (score 0):

Can use [aggregate_all](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=aggregate_all/3):

```
person_year(adam, 2000).
person_year(bob, 2001).
person_year(john, 2002).

youngest_person(Person) :-
    % Find lowest year
    aggregate_all(min(Y), person_year(_P, Y), Year),
    % Lookup person from lowest year
    person_year(Person, Year).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- youngest_person(Person).
Person = adam.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
youngest(P) :-
  findall( P:Y , birth_year(P,Y) , PYs ),
  most_recent_year( PYs, Y ),
  member(P:Y,Ps)
  .

most_recent_year( [_:Y|PYs], R ) :- most_recent_year(PYs,Y,R) .

most_recent_year( []        , R , R ) .
most_recent_year( [_:Y|PYs] , T , R ) :- Y > T , ! , most_recent_year(PYs,Y,R).
most_recent_year( [_|PYs]   , T , R ) :-             most_recent_year(PYs,T,R).
```